# Restart script when error happens and continue with right line in csv file

Tags: python, selenium

hi guys its my first time to ask help here i hope you can help me 
i have this code that i write it

```
def my_function():
try :
    with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
        data = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=','))

        i = 1
        while i <= 10:
            i += 1
            fname = data[i][0]
            lname = data[i][1]

            options = Options()
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
            driver.get("https://www.test.net/")


            #Do staff


except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    driver.quit()
    time.sleep(1)
    print('******RESTART******')
    my_function()


my_function()
```

well i'm trying to make this script run without stop .. the problem that i'm facing is when it stops for example in line number 8     (i = 8) and restart again ,it starts from first line (i = 1) .
i want the script to restart from line 8 and continue to 9 , 10 ...

can you please guide me to the right solution .. thank you

Comment: Not really understanding what you mean, but if I had to guess it would be that you want to continue through the loop if an error is thrown, rather than restart the whole function. Why not just put your try/except inside of your while loop?

Comment: You should catch the exception inside the `while` loop and `continue` instead of calling the function again. You will end up with a stack overflow if you keep recursing endlessly like you are currently doing.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is making this far more difficult than it needs to be.

First, you almost certainly don't want to wrap this entire block of code in a "catch all" exception handler.  You want your exception handling to be sufficiently specific (limited) that you can do something meaningful with the exception.  For example:

```
#!python
# Assumes Python version 3 or later
import sys, csv

filename='myfile.csv'
with open(filename as f:
    try:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
    for record in reader:
        if len(record) != 2:
            # log error and continue
            print('Malformed records in {}: {}'.format(filename, reader.line_num), file=sys.stderr)
            continue
         # do stuff with this record, knowing it has exactly two fields:
         fname = record[0]
         lname = record[1]
         # etc ...
    except csv.Error as e:
        print('Error handling {} at line {}: {}'.format(filename, reader.line_num, e), file=sys.stderr)
```

Note that your errors probably weren't specifically in the `csv` module.  It's pretty tolerant of malformed lines.  But I'm showing how to wrap the reader and processing code within exception handling just for that.  Your error was probably an **`IndexError`** (trying to access an item past the number of items in a list ... outside of its valid indexing range.  It's better to just check the length of each record rather than use exception handling for that ... though it's possible either way.

There's a quite reasonable example (very similar code) in the documentation for the standard libraries: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Also, stylistically, I'd suggest that a named tuple or a lightweight class (using `__slots__`) for managing these records.  This would allow you to use dot notation to access the `.fname` and `.lname` of each rather than using `[x]` and numeric indexing.  (Numeric indexing gets progressively more cumbersome and error prone as your code complexity increases).

Answer (score 0):

You can set `i` to a key word argument with a default of `1` then on each exception pass the current `i` when you restart your function so it picks up from there.

This is a simplified example of what I'm recommending following the same general method you are using in your question (but with fake data so I can run it without having your CSV file).

```py
def my_function(i=1):
    try:
        if i == 4:  # to prevent forever recursion
            return
        else:
            print(i)  # keep track of loops
            i += 1
            x = int('te')   # causes an error
    except ValueError:
        my_function(i)   # send current i back through

my_function(i=0)
```

Comment: i'll try to implant this solution .. thank you for your contribution

Comment: Great, please click the checkmark next to the answer and vote if it answers your question. Comment here if you need more help with implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your quick response .. i tried the solution provided by –Kevin Welch and –Selcuk  it works fine for me thx
here is the solution

```
def my_function():
try :
    with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
        data = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=','))

        i = 1
        while i <= 10:
            i += 1
            try :

                fname = data[i][0]
                lname = data[i][1]

                options = Options()
                driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
                driver.get("https://www.test.net/")

                # Do staff

            except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            driver.quit()
            time.sleep(1)
            print('******RESTAR******')
            continue

my_function()
```